# Python error urllib.request error in pycharm

Tags: python

Getting the following error in when running this code using Pycharm

```
import random
import urllib.request



def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrive(url, full_name)

download_web_image("https://realpython.com/learn/python-first-steps/images/pythonlogo.jpg")
```

Comment: And what error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You spelt urlretrieve wrong `urlretrive -> urlretrieve`:

```
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
```